How do I calculate durations between timestamps for each user in table grouped by day?
I have a transaction table that I want to pull data from. The transaction table records a timestamp for each record sent to the table in addition to other fields including the user it is associated to.
I want the output to group the transactions by day for each person, but I also want to calculate the duration between each timestamp for each specific user. I am able to get the duration between MAX and MIN timestamps for the entire day for each person, but I am unable to get the duration between each individual transaction for each day. I've tried CTE scripts using row numbers without success. Here is a working script that pulls duration for the entire day:
SELECT 
    MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE),
    MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE),
    [TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION],
    [TRANSACTION_LOCATION],
    [TRANSACTION_ID],
    [LAST_NAME],
    [FIRST_NAME],
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE),MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE)) AS [DURATION]
FROM [DB].[DBO].[TRANSACTION_TABLE]
GROUP BY
    CAST(TRANSACTION_DATE AS DATE),
    [TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION],
    [TRANSACTION_LOCATION],
    [TRANSACTION_ID],
    [LAST_NAME],
    [FIRST_NAME]
ORDER BY
    [LAST_NAME]



Please provide example data and a table showing the expected output

SQL Server <> MySQL and MySQL does not use T-SQL. I've removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

If you are using SQL Server, then a timestamp (rowversion) won't help you; it is a binary(8) value, and has nothing do with times.

Maybe this fiddle will help https://dbfiddle.uk/hY55gE3P

@BartMcEndree Yes, that did help. The output that is there is what I am getting, but what I am looking for would be durations between all transactions for each day for each user (not MAX and MIN). So for Bob Smith I would want to see the duration between the 1st and 2nd transaction then the 2nd and 3rd transaction for 1/1

Be careful with datediff, especially at the hour level. It does not return the number of hours elapsed between two dates. Instead it return the number of hour thresholds is crosses. For example the datediff for hour will return 1 when the minute is 59 and the next minute starts. select datediff(hour, '20240809 10:59', '20240809 11:00')

You might benefit from using LAG instead of grouping by day
SELECT 
    TRANSACTION_DATE,    
    [TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION],
    [TRANSACTION_LOCATION],
    [TRANSACTION_ID],
    [LAST_NAME],
    [FIRST_NAME],
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,LAG(TRANSACTION_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY [LAST_NAME] ORDER BY  [LAST_NAME],TRANSACTION_DATE),TRANSACTION_DATE) AS [DURATION]
FROM [TRANSACTION_TABLE]
ORDER BY
    [LAST_NAME],TRANSACTION_DATE

fiddle

That did work if I set the transaction date to WHERE [TRANSACTION_DATE] >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)). If I want to run the query across multiple dates is there a way to reset the duration to 0 for each day for each person? Right now, if I do a BETWEEN across multiple days the duration is a running tally from day before for the first transaction

Try adding the date to the LAG partition. [Last_Name], cast(TRANSACTION_DATE as DATE)

Just a suggested tweak: Use OVER(PARTITION BY LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, cast(TRANSACTION_DATE as DATE) ORDER BY  TRANSACTION_DATE). (Added missing FIRST_NAME to PARTITION BY and dropped the unnecessary LAST_NAME from the ORDER BY.)
